# Spring Boot actuator default endpoints not starting: /info, /metrics/, /health

Tags: rest, spring-boot, java-8

I'm running a Spring Boot 1.5.9-RELEASE app. I used Pivotal's maven archetype which includes both spring boot & spring actuator and also all of the necessary dependencies. I've also posted the output of the start-up logs with org.springframework logging turned up to INFO level. Why aren't these default endpoints which according to spring docs are supposed to be starting not starting? I'd really appreciate your input. I've also posted my application.properties file. when i hit the endpoint in postman i get the following response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1515490133441,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/info"
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=7299
security.user.password=password
num.to.output=1000
occurrence.of.garbage=9
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.info.sensitive=false
```

output of start-up logs:

```
10:31:54,332 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
10:31:54,332 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
10:31:54,332 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/Users/zenith/Documents/workspace/wsjoiner-service/target/classes/logback.xml]
10:31:54,382 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
10:31:54,383 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:31:54,388 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
10:31:54,424 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
10:31:54,424 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
10:31:54,424 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
10:31:54,424 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
10:31:54,426 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [ROLLING_FILE]
10:31:54,430 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1073502961 - No compression will be used
10:31:54,431 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1073502961 - Will use the pattern logs/WSJoinerServiceApp.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log for the active file
10:31:54,434 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'dd-MM-yyyy' from file name pattern 'logs/WSJoinerServiceApp.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log'.
10:31:54,434 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
10:31:54,436 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Tue Jan 09 10:29:37 CET 2018
10:31:54,437 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
10:31:54,439 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ROLLING_FILE] - Active log file name: logs/WSJoinerServiceApp.log
10:31:54,439 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[ROLLING_FILE] - File property is set to [logs/WSJoinerServiceApp.log]
10:31:54,440 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to INFO
10:31:54,440 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.blairtech.wsjoiner] to INFO
10:31:54,440 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.blairtech.wsjoiner] to false
10:31:54,440 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.blairtech.wsjoiner]
10:31:54,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [ROLLING_FILE] to Logger[com.blairtech.wsjoiner]
10:31:54,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
10:31:54,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
10:31:54,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [ROLLING_FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
10:31:54,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
10:31:54,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5e5792a0 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2018-01-09 10:31:54 [main] INFO  c.b.wsjoiner.WSJoinerServiceApp - Starting WSJoinerServiceApp on z-macdaddy.local with PID 24339 (/Users/zenith/Documents/workspace/wsjoiner-service/target/classes started by zenith in /Users/zenith/Documents/workspace/wsjoiner-service)
2018-01-09 10:31:54 [main] INFO  c.b.wsjoiner.WSJoinerServiceApp - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-09 10:31:54 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7fc2413d: startup date [Tue Jan 09 10:31:54 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-09 10:31:54 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'jsonResponseGenerator' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.blairtech.wsjoiner.response.JsonResponseGenerator]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/Users/zenith/Documents/workspace/wsjoiner-io/target/classes/com/blairtech/wsjoiner/response/JsonResponseGenerator.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=WSJoinerIOConfig; factoryMethodName=jsonResponseGenerator; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/blairtech/wsjoiner/WSJoinerIOConfig.class]]
2018-01-09 10:31:54 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'xmlResponseGenerator' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.blairtech.wsjoiner.response.XmlResponseGenerator]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/Users/zenith/Documents/workspace/wsjoiner-io/target/classes/com/blairtech/wsjoiner/response/XmlResponseGenerator.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=WSJoinerIOConfig; factoryMethodName=xmlResponseGenerator; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/blairtech/wsjoiner/WSJoinerIOConfig.class]]
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 7299 (http)
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 870 ms
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-01-09 10:31:55 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7fc2413d: startup date [Tue Jan 09 10:31:54 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/sink/a],methods=[POST],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.blairtech.wsjoiner.messages.WSSinkResponseMessage> com.blairtech.wsjoiner.controller.WSJoinerSinkController.postRequest(com.blairtech.wsjoiner.messages.WSSinkInputMessage)
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/source/a],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.blairtech.wsjoiner.controller.WSJoinerSourceController.jsonRequest()
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/source/b],methods=[GET],produces=[application/xml]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.blairtech.wsjoiner.controller.WSJoinerSourceController.xmlRequest()
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6d171ce0, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5bb7643d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2c306a57, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7a2e0858, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@6edcd0d8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4074023c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5b12012e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@22bd2039, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@38eb2fb0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@723ed581, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@9a2ec9b]
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 7299 (http)
2018-01-09 10:31:56 [main] INFO  c.b.wsjoiner.WSJoinerServiceApp - Started 
WSJoinerServiceApp in 2.011 seconds (JVM running for 2.74)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a project with Spring Boot 1.5.9 and the dependencies Web and Actuator at http://start.spring.io/ and afterwards use your application.properties, the endpoint `http://localhost:7299/info` is available and returns

```
{}
```

Therefore, I suggest that you create such a project at http://start.spring.io/ and compare it to your setup or that you directly start from the generated project.

The actuator endpoints are also listed in the logs and this part is missing from your logs:

```
2018-01-10 08:46:36.840  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/shutdown || /shutdown.json],methods=[POST],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.ShutdownMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.841  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.846  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 08:46:36.846  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-01-10 08:46:36.846  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.847  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
2018-01-10 08:46:36.848  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 08:46:36.850  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.854  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.856  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 08:46:36.856  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.862  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 08:46:36.863  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.865  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2018-01-10 08:46:36.866  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.868  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.869  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 08:46:36.870  INFO 17243 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

Comment: i  followed the instructions from spring.io which says to use as a parent pivotal's maven pom. there's a spring-boot-starter maven archetype that i used that everyone uses.

i can tell they are missing from my logs which is why i posted them. there's a ton of default endpoints including the ones i listed that also didn't start. it's covered in chapter 47 of the spring.io spring boot docs titled: Endpoints

Comment: Without seeing more of your setup it is really hard to tell what is wrong. The setup that you describe sounds good. Did you compare your pom.xml with the one generated by http://start.spring.io/ ?